# How to use mmap like malloc?

Tags: c, mmap

I'm trying to allocate memory for 10x of my list struct then use it for my linked list but I keep getting a segmentation fault.

Valgrind

```sh
==3806== Invalid write of size 4
==3806==    at 0x4005FD: main (comp.c:14)
==3806==  Address 0xffffffffffffffff is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

Sample Code

```c
#include <sys/mman.h>

typedef struct list {
    int num;
    struct list *next;
}list;

int main()
{
    list *nodes = mmap(NULL, sizeof(list) * 10, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE, -1, 0);

    nodes[0].num = 1;
    nodes[0].next = NULL;

}
```

Comment: [man 2 mmap](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) -- look at the **RETURN**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `0xffffffffffffffff` almost surely means that `mmap` failed.  If you want to use it to allocate memory like `malloc`, you have to do error checking just as you would for `malloc`, except that you need to test the returned value against `MAP_FAILED` instead of `NULL`.

The failure is probably because you are trying to map a nonexistent file descriptor `-1`.  This is only allowed when the `MAP_ANONYMOUS` flag is specified, which you did not include.

Comment: MAP_ANONYMOUS is not recognized by clang.
`
comp.c:19:101: error: use of undeclared identifier 'MAP_ANONYMOUS'
    struct list *nodes = mmap(NULL, sizeof(struct list) * 10, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
`

Comment: Fixed it had to add #define _GNU_SOURCE at the top of the code.